# What is the most reliable approach to detecting browser feature support?

Tags: javascript

Let's say I want to detect support for notifications (http://notifications.spec.whatwg.org/) in a JavaScript library.

I can use `window.Notification !== undefined`. But what if the users of the library (or another library) also have some kind of global `Notification` object defined for completely different purpose?

On the other hand, what if the other library is a polyfill? Then their `Notification` object is acceptable. Should I test for all methods in addition to testing for the global object?

Update:
I have noticed an interesting thing in one [notifications polyfill](https://github.com/kbjr/Notifications):

```
ret[toString] = function() {
    return 'function Notification() { [native code] }';
};
```

How reliable is relying on something like that to detect whether it is a native/polyfill object?

Comment: You should clearly spell out the environmental requirements for your library. Then you don't really need to worry about it. Let the user make sure that other libraries will cooperate.

Comment: I agree. If the user is crazy enough to use libraries that pollute the global namespace, there is not much you can do, right?

Comment: That's a good answer, but only if there is no other options. I like to save people from potential mistakes whenever I can.

Comment: Sure, you could test every possible variation that could  possibly break your code. Testing for all the functions isn't enough. You'd need to set up a set of assertions to ensure that the functions behave exactly as your code expects. Ultimately, you need to decide if you want to be a software developer, or a nanny. ;-)

Comment: ...and regarding your update, I think you can see that it's not reliable, since some non-conforming code could also do the same `toString()` trick.

Comment: @CrazyTrain yes, but I am not guarding against malicious code or professional foot-shooting, I am guarding against simple mistakes. `Notification` is a pretty common name for something like that so conflict is quite possible.

Comment: Sure it's possible. I'm not saying it's not. Just seems to me like you're trying to solve problems that someone else created for themselves. If that's what you want to do, then fine, but IMO, if someone breaks their own environment with non-conforming code then they need to suffer the fallout for those decisions. I'd spend that time providing clear documentation instead.

Comment: @CrazyTrain: Fair enough, btw you can post your opinion (no reliable way to do that) as an answer and I'll accept it if I do not find/get any other options/answers within reasonable time.

Comment: Tell you what, if you don't get anything else, why don't you sum up in an answer what you've decided. There's an element of subjectivity to this, since standards of what guards ought to be in place will vary with the individual. My main point is that nearly everything in a JavaScript environment can be corrupted somehow. I'll let you take it from there. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So essentially there are two choices.

First is to try and rely on `'function Notification() { [native code] }'` `toString` value, as it is being set by some polyfills at least. Unfortunately, this not reliable, as I found no information on whether it is a common approach within polyfill authors and whether it is a reliable return value in browsers.

Another option, as suggested in comments, is to ignore potential conflicts and just go forward just testing for existence. That's what I went with for now.

Answer (score 0):

You can always take the jQuery approach and redefine anything that is referencing the pre-existing window.Notifications with something like:

```
window._Notification = window.Notification;
```

Paul Irish has a bit in [this video](http://www.paulirish.com/2010/10-things-i-learned-from-the-jquery-source/) that does a pretty good job of explaining how that works.

That way, you can continue the implementation of whatever other feature they're using, while still including yours as well.

Hope that helps. :)

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. He wants to know whether he can _use_ `Notification`, not how to overwrite it without breaking anything.