# Is there a clever way to check from code whether asm.js is active or not?

Tags: javascript, asm.js

Does anyone know of a way to do it from JavaScript without relying on browser version and just assuming that it works?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the most reliable approach to detecting browser feature support?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17119105/what-is-the-most-reliable-approach-to-detecting-browser-feature-support)

Comment: Can I ask why you need this? asm.js code will run on any javascript engine, the difference is only speed.

Comment: True, I'm just considering putting up some badges on a page that supports both PNaCl and asm.js for what it does. The check in the linked question above actually does work for methods exported from asm.js modules so I guess that's the answer.

Answer (score 0):

As per the question linked by James Donnelly above, calling toString() on methods exported from asm.js modules will return

```
'function method() { [native code] }'
```

if the module has been compiled successfully and the JS source otherwise.

Comment: No longer works with the latest FireFox. There seems to be no straightforward way to detect it anymore.